# Injecting 'root' service into Module service

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

### Issue

I am trying to inject a `'root'` service into an `AppModule` service, which causes problems in resolving the `AppService`.

> NullInjectorError: No provider for AppService!

This is tested with Angular 9, bot Ivy enabled and disabled, and with Angular 8.

### Example

The following is used to reproduce the issue: **https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mk2wrx**

**app.service.ts**

```
import { TestService } from "./test.service";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { AppModule } from "./app.module";

@Injectable({ providedIn: AppModule })
export class AppService {
  constructor(private readonly testService: TestService) { }

  public getTitle() {
    return this.testService.doSomething();
  }
}
```

**test.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { AppModule } from "./app.module";

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class TestService {
  public doSomething() {
    return 'I did it!';
  }
}
```

Even defining both services as `{ providedIn: AppModule }` does not seem to work. The only way this works is by providing the services as `{ providedIn: 'root' }`.

---

Looking at this example, from my understanding, this should work in theory.

The injector hierarchy should be as follows: first the `root ModuleInjector` and then the `AppModule ModuleInjector`. The `AppService` looks at its [`ModuleInjector`](https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection#moduleinjector) (the `AppModule`s injector) and tries to resolve the `ModuleInjector` hierarchy by traversing to the parent injector (the `root ModuleInjector`). So from `AppModule` to `'root'`.

At least, that is assuming traversing the injector hierarchy is meant with ["looks in the ModuleInjector hierarchy"](https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection#resolution-rules).

Answer (score 3):

You have to add AppService in the file app.module.ts in the providers section like this :

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent],
  providers: [AppService],
  bootstrap:[ AppComponent ]
})
```

**Result** : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6jmgtu?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Comment: Thanks for your response. The `{ provideIn: <value> }` notation I used, is actually a recommended replacement for the `providers: []` syntax. See https://angular.io/guide/providers#providedin-and-ngmodules. It should imply the 'same'.

Comment: How did you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you make a

1. new module suppose **xyzService.Module.ts**.
2. import that in    App.module.ts.
3. then in your service.

   **`@Injectable({ providedIn: xyzServiceModuleName })`**

then it will work.

As now a days we use '**root**' in service injectable and **root** is by default injected in App.module (// main module of the app).

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root'})
```

i guess you can't add main module in provided in for that 'root' is there.

or if you don't want to use providedIn , then you can normally import in providers section of a module.